# Magento 2 js error appears after adding new custom component to checkout_index_index.xml

Tags: magento2, error, javascript, component

js error at checkout page:

```
  collection.js:53 Uncaught TypeError: elem.initContainer is not a function
```

new component:
[Magento 2 How to add onKeyUp to a text field in customer checkout address form?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/129856/magento-2-how-to-add-onkeyup-to-a-text-field-in-customer-checkout-address-form/129901#129901)

How to deal with it? Thanks.

Comment: Have you delete pub/staic folder and run deploy command after changes?

Answer (score 1):

This type of error comes when you call the function on non object. Check following reference links.

- [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026891/javascript-uncaught-typeerror-object-is-not-a-function-associativity-question) Javascript “Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function”
- [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856140/javascript-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-addeventlistener-of-null) Javascript: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null”

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that JS component cannot be loaded, probably you should re-deploy static components;

To figure out what component is missing you can add conditional breakpoint:

[image]

and then moving up to two calls on stack trace, see query info in `_resolveRequest`:

[image]